# What is the privilege for account unlock in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c

I want to understand the privileges better, but I'm not able to find some useful info using Google.

I thought that I needed `ALTER USER` privilege to be able to unlock user and change password. **But** currently I'm on a machine, where I **can** change the password (also for other users), but I'm **not able** to unlock locked user. Why is that?

I tried also

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS ;
```

ant the result is:

```
TEST_USER   CREATE OPERATOR NO  NO
TEST_USER   ALTER SESSION   NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE SESSION  NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE DATABASE LINK    NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE SYNONYM  NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE INDEXTYPE    NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW    NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE TRIGGER  NO  NO
TEST_USER   GLOBAL QUERY REWRITE    NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE SEQUENCE NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE CLUSTER  NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE TYPE NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE PROCEDURE    NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE VIEW NO  NO
TEST_USER   CREATE TABLE    NO  NO
```

Error, when tried unlock:

```
alter user other_user account unlock
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Comment: You wrote you had `ALTER USER`, still it's not in the output. Provide the full output with a successful password change and unlock attempt, and include `SELECT * FROM SESSION_PRIVS` instead if `USER_SYS_PRIVS` with the user you are trying to unlock others.

Comment: My testing was wrong, I'm sorry - closing...

Comment: Kindly delete the question - makes like easier for everybody!

Comment: Believe me, I wanted, but: "Question with answers cannot be deleted" :-/

Answer (score 1):

you have not shown the roles TEST_USER is granted.  Likely they have been granted the DBA role which allows ALTER USER.

see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15665) for details.  This query will show the roles a user has

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee = 'TEST_USER'
```

of course this requires privileges too, unless you have the CATALOG role, if you select from this table you can alter a user

Comment: Thanks for a reply, `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` for the user is empty and I have no privileges for DBA_ROLE_PRIVS view, but should be the same, right? So no DBA role is granted. If so, I'd be able to unlock the user/account, right?

Comment: Thanks for documentation, I tried `session_privs` and `session_roles` from documentation and  nothing changed - 15 privs + 0 roles.

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER USER` should be enough, see below.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create user u1 identified by u1;

User created.

SQL> create user u2 identified by u2 account lock;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to u1, u2;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant alter user to u1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.
SQL> select * from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
ALTER USER
CREATE SESSION

SQL> select * from session_roles;

no rows selected

SQL> alter user u2 account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> conn u2/u2
Connected.
SQL>
```

Comment: Maybe it was not clear from the question, so I modified a bit - I have this privilege, but still cannot unlock the account.